# Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.x

Tags: android, proguard, inflate-exception

Application working fine in debug build type but later I generated signed APK and tried to run app but got an error on signed APK.

Here I share some other resource for more clarification.

**BuildType:**

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

**Proguardrules:**

```
-dontwarn com.roughike.bottombar.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
23486-23486/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia, PID: 23486
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia/com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class x
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class x
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.x(SourceFile:430)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.w(SourceFile:323)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.b(SourceFile:284)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(SourceFile:139)
                                                   at com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:46)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class x
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:945)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.x(SourceFile:430) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.w(SourceFile:323) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.b(SourceFile:284) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(SourceFile:139) 
                                                   at com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:46) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.x" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:681)
                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:698)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:945) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.x(SourceFile:430) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.w(SourceFile:323) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.k.b(SourceFile:284) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(SourceFile:139) 
                                                   at com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:46) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.x
                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                        ... 29 more
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".activity.SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".receiver.DownloadReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fastfashion.videostatusmedia.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarTheme">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/main_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_inActiveTabAlpha="1.0"
        app:bb_inActiveTabColor="#7e7e7e"
        app:bb_titleTextAppearance="@style/BottomBarTextAppearance"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_main_tabs"
        app:bb_titleTypeFace="fonts/prestij-regular.otf"
        app:bb_behavior="shy"
        android:background="#f7f5f5"
        app:bb_showShadow="false"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/transparentSearchOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black_trans"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Toolbar mainToolbar;
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;
    private MaterialSearchView searchView;
    private boolean isDoubleBackPressed = false;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            showShortToast("Press again BACK to exit.");
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(PrefManager.getInstance().isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }

        MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.ad_app_id));
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mainToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);

        mBottomBar = findViewById(R.id.main_bottom_bar);

        mBottomBar.setTabSelectionInterceptor(new TabSelectionInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldInterceptTabSelection(int oldTabId, int newTabId) {
                if(newTabId == R.id.tab_upload) {
                    showLongToast("Coming Soon....");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mBottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(int tabId) {
                switch (tabId) {
                    case R.id.tab_home:
                        loadFragment(R.string.title_home, HomeFragment.newInstance("default"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_trending:
                        loadFragment(R.string.title_trending, HomeFragment.newInstance("trending"));
                        break;
                    case R.id.tab_downloads:
                        loadFragment(R.string.title_downloads, DownloadFragment.newInstance());
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        initSearchBar();
    }

    private void initSearchBar() {
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        final View transparentSearchScreen = findViewById(R.id.transparentSearchOverlay);
        searchView.setBackIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_arrow_back));
        searchView.setCloseIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_action_navigation_close));
        this.searchView.setHintTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.darker_gray));
        searchView.dismissSuggestions();

        searchView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.white));
        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {
                transparentSearchScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                transparentSearchScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        transparentSearchScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(searchView.isOpaque()) {
                    searchView.closeSearch();
                }
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                if(query.equals("")) {
                    showShortToast("Enter something for search");
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(SearchActivity.EXTRA_SEARCH_STRING, query);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    searchView.setQuery("", false);
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        this.searchView.setMenuItem(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_share:
                shareApp();
                break;
            case R.id.action_rate:
                rateApp();
                break;
            case R.id.action_feedback:
                feedbackApp();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void loadFragment(int id, final Fragment fragment) {
        final String title = getString(id);
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setToolbarTitle(title);
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, title);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }
    }

    private void setToolbarTitle(String title) {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(this.searchView.isSearchOpen()) {
            this.searchView.closeSearch();
            return;
        }

        if(isDoubleBackPressed) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        if(R.id.tab_home != mBottomBar.getCurrentTabId()) {
            mBottomBar.selectTabWithId(R.id.tab_home);
            return;
        }

        isDoubleBackPressed = true;
        this.handler.postDelayed(runnable,300);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isDoubleBackPressed = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    private void shareApp() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Utility.shareSubject);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\nGet all categories status in one app. Share status and become popular in social market. \n\n 'Video Status'\n\n" + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName() + "\n\n");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
    }

    private void rateApp() {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
        Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            myAppLinkToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
        }
            myAppLinkToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        try {
            startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));
        }
    }

    private void feedbackApp() {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "fastfashion111@gmail.com", null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Status Video - Feedback");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Write your feedback content here.");
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Feedback"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            showShortToast("There is no email client installed.");
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Toast toast;

    protected void showShortToast(String msg) {
        if(toast == null)
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        else
            toast.setText(msg);

        toast.show();
    }

    protected void showLongToast(String msg) {
        if(toast == null)
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        else
            toast.setText(msg);

        toast.show();
    }
}
```

If it needs some other code please tell me so I can share here. I already tried to find out solution  on stackoverflow and I didn't find anything at all.

Comment: try with `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` set to false.

Comment: @VivekMishra Sorry for forgot to mention that i already tried and it's working fine but i'm expecting to reduce APK size so want to carry both.

Comment: then you have to identify which classes are being removed in release builds and put them in your proguard rules.

Comment: @VivekMishra For identify that class i used **proguardgui** tool in that i load stacktrace and maping file but still failed to identify. there are any other effective option to identify?

Comment: are you using some third party library in your activity layout file ?

Comment: @VivekMishra yes, i'm use here some third party libraries such as ExoMedia, MaterialSearchView.

Comment: I can't see anything in your proguard related to exomedia or your material search view. You have added for android default searchview not your material searchview

Comment: I think this is creating problem..try to load activity without this.."com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar"

Comment: I think there is something which you forgot to inflate with your java class i.e, MainActivity.java. And what is BaseActivity ? Have you create a custom class for this which extends AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: @Ankita, I created custom class called BaseActivity inside that i just created two methods for toast displaying. Please check added question.

Comment: @VivekMishra as you suggest me i added both library in dontwarn and generate signed apk and tried but same error generating.

Comment: My bad. You have to add keep class instead of don't warn for those libraries.

Comment: Hi, can you try adding these 2 lines `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable` and `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile` to your `progurad-rules.pro`. This will tell you the exact line number of the error and will also let you see the source file name where the error is

Comment: In your java file iside initSearchBar() you are using    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view); you should write it as    searchView = (MaterialSearchView)findViewById(R.id.search_view); and same for the Toolbar and BottomBar also.

Comment: @k1slay attached stacktrace generated with your suggested proguard rules and if see in stacktrace there are show line no. **MainActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:46)** and it's point to setContentView.

Comment: @sagarchavda Does it have the line number for the xml as well ?

Comment: @Ankita I'm using build tool 26.0.1 and studio suggest me that casting is redundant so i removed it. Still casting  required ?

Comment: @k1slay In stacktrace i was got only one clickable view that a SourceFile:46. I already attached whole stacktrace if you can find xml line inside that then it will helpful for me.

Comment: @Ankita i tried with add casting but error is still showing.

Comment: @SagarChavda Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: For anyone that stumbles upon this years later as I have; Pro Guard was stripping out a layout from a library I was using but only when `minifyEnabled`. I had to explicitly declare to keep this layout in a `keep.xml` as specified here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources